# PHP - help appending to textarea values

Tags: php

I currently have the example below working to take each value from a textarea, and split it as follows `name1` `name2` `name3` and so forth.  I would like to append a single quote on each side of the values, followed by a comma like this `'name1',` `'name2',` `'name3'`.  Finally I'd like to put all of this into a single `$string` value that I can reference later.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

```
<?php

//trim off excess whitespace off the whole
$text = trim($_POST['ServerName']);

//explode all separate lines into an array
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);

//trim all lines contained in the array.
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim');

//loop through the lines
foreach($textAr as $line){
echo "$line";

}

?>
```

Comment: check out the `implode()` function

Comment: `$textAr = "'".implode("', '", $textAr)."'";` no need to use `foreach` use this code instead...

Comment: Jason thanks for your reply.  I added the implode line you provided after the $textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim'); line.  Is that the correct position to put it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add quotes: `foreach ($textAr as $k=>$v) { $textAr[$k] = "'".$v."'"; }`
2. Concat: `$text = implode(", ", $textAr);

Comment: @Jason is totally right. You can omit (1) and add the quotes using implode()

Answer (score 0):

@jason-000 Thanks for your help I was able to figure out what you meant after doing some more research.  I removed the foreach loop and was able to get it to output the way I wanted as follows -

```
$text = trim($_POST['ServerName']);
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);
$values = array_values($textAr);
$string = implode("','", $values);
$string = "'".$string."'";
$output = "(".$string.")";
```

I end up with ('Server1 ','Server2 ','Server3') which is fine.  Not sure why it added the space before the last ' except on the last value.